# HTTP Status Code when the Parent Resource is not longer live

Tags: rest, web, web-applications, api-design

> In our Organization, the items in our inventory are called `stocks`. Each `stock` has a `sortScore` associated with it. An internal API is exposed to another team in the organization to update the sortScore of the `stock`.

**PUT /api/stock/{stockid}/sortscore**

> This request updates the sortScore of the stock. It may happen that the stock is no more `live(it is sold)`, but for some reason, the internal API for updating the sortScore is still hit by another team.
>
> According to me, here the resource is `sortScore` and the parent resource is the `stock`, which isn't live anymore(It used to be live at some point of time). Even though the stock is no more `live`, we still keep a record of it somewhere in our Database.
>
> Some of us are having arguement about the HTTP Status code we are sending when the `stock is not live anymore`. Since the resource is not available at the intended `Resource Identifier(URL)`, we are sending **NOT FOUND**. But some of our colleagues are saying that since the stock used to be live at some point of time, the `Status Code` should be of **2xx series** with the message that `This stock is not live anymore`.
>
> Now I am here to know what the people from `stackoverflow` thinks about what the correct answer should be?

Answer (score 1):

So an important thing to understand about REST is that the concepts of "parent resource" and "child resource" *don't really exist*.

As far as REST, and HTTP, is concerned; `/a/b/c` doesn't necessarily have anything to do with `/a/b` or `/a/b/c/d`.  Each resource is its own thing, with its own representation(s).

So you should be thinking about

```
PUT /api/stock/{stockid}/sortscore
```

In isolation.

Since you aren't allowing the clients to change the resource, using `2xx` status code is not the right idea.  A 2xx status code would not only indicate that the request had been successful, but would also encourage consumers to flush their caches and so on.

`404 Not Found` isn't quite the right idea, since a `PUT` should [create a resource](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) if there isn't one present already.

> The PUT method requests that the state of the target resource be created or replaced with the state defined by the representation enclosed in the request message payload

It sounds to me as though "it's not live any more" means that consumers are no longer allowed to modify the state of the resource.  That in turn suggests that the status code you want is [405 Method Not Allowed](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.5)

> The 405 (Method Not Allowed) status code indicates that the method received in the request-line is known by the origin server but not supported by the target resource.

Answer (score 1):

A common status code for this is `409 Conflict`. The idea of `409 Conflict` is that even though everything is fine with your request, the current state of the server prevents it from being successful.

The current state in your case is a *different resource* not existing anymore. This is in conflict with the `PUT` request you are doing.